# connecting to postgres through hibernate using tls/ssl

Tags: hibernate, ssl, tls1.2, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to enable TLS/SSL connection between app server and postgres database.  I've followed the directions from postgres and I have disabled all connections except secure.  As per the docs, I've tested the connection with psql command and I can connect securely.  My environment has contains both datasource, JDBC Driver and hibernate.  I've been able to connect securely with a datasource and JDBC driver, but no luck with hibernate.  Below is the string that is working with datasource/JDBC driver.

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://%s:%d/postgres?user=%s&password=%s&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
```

For hibernate (not working):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DB?ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DB?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DB?ssl=true"/>
```

I'm using Hibernate org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider if that matters.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database?ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory</property>
```

`&amp;` instead of `&`

Comment: '&amp;'   - add <amp;> after the &